# Function value as $color argument in Sass darken()

Tags: sass

I'm trying to use a color value specified in a map as the $color argument for darken(), like so:

`border: 1px solid darken(color(lowlight), 10);`

This relies on a couple of simple functions and maps I've written (extraneous values removed):

```
@function gray($color) {
    @return map-get($grays, $color);
}

@function color($color) {
    @return map-get($colors, $color);
}

$grays: (
    x-light: #f8f8f8
);

$colors: (
    lowlight: gray(x-light)
);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

It works if I supply it with a variable, but not with a function value. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I can load your short example into a codepen and it works fine. So without a full way to reproduce I could only take a guess that your scss function -> color map -> custom functions aren't being loaded in the correct order of inception as @import's somewhere since inline like you show everything is in the same context.

Comment: This is using Vue and Nuxt. The error comes when hot-reloading, and the Sass is loaded via @import. It seems like the problem comes in when using sequential functions. I can reference either function as a value, provided its value isn't also a function value.

Comment: So in the portion being hot reloaded, are the dependencies (functions, mixins, whatever) also @import'd to the module they're used in? That would be where I'd look first.

Comment: Dependencies are imported at the top of the SCSS file, and that's where the functions and variables come in. I'm able to use them elsewhere, just not within another function.